# Can a ADO.NET SQL command parameter contain a sub-query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, parameterized-query

Is it possible to create a SQL `select max(id)` as a variable inside a query?

This doesn't work:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ordreid (ordrenr,ordreid) SELECT @ordrenr, @ordreid";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordrenr", nyordre);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordreid", ("MAX(ordreid)+1 FROM ordreid"));
command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Here is a photo of what I'd like to do. 5 customers have added items to their orders. Customer 1 has 3 items, customer 2 has 4 items, customer 3 has 1 item, and so on...

This way I have 1 `ordreid` even through the order could consist of 30 items.

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using an `IDENTITY` column?

Comment: The Identity column increases the id. I want that specific table to have 2 colums (ordreid, ordrenr). Ordrenr should increase when items are added, but ordreid should only increase if the user makes a whole new items list.

Answer (score 2):

*Query parameters **cannot** include SQL verbatim.*

This is how such prepared statements prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as they are *not* directly inserted. Rather only the corresponding *data* is used in the query - in this case that is the *string* that contains SQL, and results in invalid SQL syntax.

The SQL text then needs to look similar to the following, although this probably does *not* do what is desired. (Asking how to do the higher level task will lead to actually useful queries/approaches.)

```
@"INSERT INTO ordreid (ordrenr, ordreid)
  SELECT @ordrenr, MAX(ordreid)+1
  FROM ordreid"
```

Answer (score 1):

> *`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordreid", ("MAX(ordreid)+1 FROM ordreid"));`*

The method name `AddWithValue` hints at the reason why this won't work: Parameters contain data, that is: values. They cannot represent a part of a SQL statement.

Your intention appears to be that `@ordreid` should be replaced with that piece of SQL. If this is so, then there's no reason to even have a parameter. Simply perform the substitution manually and change the `CommandText`:

```
command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO ordreid (ordrenr,  ordreid) 
                        VALUES (@ordrenr, (SELECT MAX(ordreid)+1 FROM ordreid));";
```

Note that I changed four things (apart from spreading the command text across two lines, for legibility's sake, using C#'s `@"…"` string syntax). Only the first two points are crucial:

1. I moved the `MAX(…)` SQL directly into your `CommandText`. This makes the (invalid) `@ordreid` parameter obsolete.
2. To determine the value of `MAX(ordreid) FROM ordreid`, you need a sub-query; thus the added `SELECT` before `MAX`. Otherwise, the syntax wouldn't be valid.
3. I replaced *your* `SELECT` with a [`VALUES` table value constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx). (Otherwise, because of the previous point, we'd have two `SELECT`s very close to each other, which would look somewhat confusing.)
4. I added a `;` at the end of your query. Current versions of SQL Server don't yet require such a statement terminator, but Microsoft has hinted that they might become compulsory in future versions of T-SQL. I therefore believe that it's a good habit to get into *now*.

That all being said, you should probably turn the `ordreid` column into an `IDENTITY` column and let SQL Server choose the value to be inserted (making the `SELECT MAX(…)` business obsolete). Otherwise, if two processes or threads execute the same `INSERT` command at the same time, you might end up with several rows having the same value for `ordreid`.